# Facebook LIKE button not showing

Tags: facebook-like

I put the facebook like button code as suggested by facebook developer documentation.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=416733691671772";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.domain.com/" data-send="true" data-layout="box_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-action="recommend" data-colorscheme="dark" data-font="arial"></div>
```

Strange thing is that, the code of facebook like button is there when I inspect element in firefox and chrome. And its showing on my localhost as well..

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To debug problems with the 'Like' button, always use the Facebook debug tool: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug